# export mysql result into excel/pdf/etc format using jsp

Tags: html, mysql, jsp

Is there any api/plugin/jquery available that will allow me to export a CURRENT jsp PAGE to PDF/EXCEL/CSV?

Desired output like the image below. [image: This is sample web page]

Answer (score 0):

some jquery plugin for print whole page,

1. [Print Page Plugin](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-printPage-plugin)
2. [jQuery Print Page](https://github.com/ianoxley/jqueryprintpage#readme)